# Detect User's Country in .CS File

Tags: c#, location, country

I have an application that needs to detect the user's country so I can adjust dates to that expectation for that country.  I do have JS that is working already in detecting the locale.  Now, I understand that JS is browser side and my CS file is server side.  Is there a way to either:
1) Link that JS's answer up to my CS
or
2) Detect the locale within the CS file?

Thank you for your time

Kevin

Comment: You can do it using js or c#. In stackoverflow there are lots of question about it just search and you' ll find what you need

Comment: I am finding nothing related to what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, detecting the user's country isn't really the issue. If you need to format dates, you need to use something like this to detect the current culture rather than the country:

```
CultureInfo currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

You wouldn't want to detect the country as there's plenty of users in a given country that don't use the program in that country's culture. For example, say someone has their system set to Spanish, but they live in the USA. You'd force them to use English, but using this method, you can take it directly from the system setting instead. Being dynamic is good!

That way, when you output a date, you can do something like this:

```
// Displays dt, formatted using the ShortDatePattern
// and the CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("d"));
```

Reference: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx

Comment: We already have a date formatting function within our app.  Long story short, I have a search box that needs to validate dates.  So in the US it's MM/DD/YYYY while in the UK it's DD/MM/YYYY.  So I really just need to detect the country so I can format it the way our clients have asked (which we have built already)

Comment: @KevinFischer Well again, you should use the CurrentCulture to check what *culture* the client is using and validate the days with that *culture's* format.

Comment: Also, our app is currently being used mostly in the US.  I was going to make an IF statement stating that if FOO's cultureinfo == en-us, then do this.  how would i go about that?

Comment: @KevinFischer Pretty much just like that. See this fiddle: http://dotnetfiddle.net/PpgUoP EDIT: new fiddle